# Spacy add custom component with rewrite doc.text

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to create a custom component on spacy's pipeline. I want to transform my text to lower.

My code :

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
def lower_component(doc):
    doc.text = doc.text.lower
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(lower_component, first=True)
print('Pipeline:', nlp.pipe_names)

doc = nlp("Hello world!")
doc
```

I have an

> AttributeError : attribute 'text' of 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' objects is not writable

Do you have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found ! just pass a class :

```
class Lower(object):
name = "Lower"

nlp: Language

def __init__(self, nlp: Language):
    self.nlp = nlp

def __call__(self, doc: Doc) -> Doc:
    text = doc.text
    return self.nlp.make_doc(text.lower())
```

and following :

```
nlp.add_pipe(Lower(nlp), first=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of spaCy's core principles is that spaCy's processing never modifies the text itself. If you want to lowercase your text, it should be in a preprocessing step that is run outside of spacy, before you call `nlp(text)`.

Comment: Thanks aab. I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

doc = nlp("Hello world!".lower())